# How to resolve the AbstractMethodError when upgrade to Glide 4.9.0

Tags: android-glide

this is with in a library module, so it should not use the generated API

upgrade to Glide 4.9.0

```
versions.glide = "4.9.0"

implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$versions.glide"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$versions.glide"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:$versions.glide"
```

updated the code, no place is using GlideApp

```
fun ImageView.loadImg(imageUrl: String) {

// 3.8.0
//    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
//        Glide.clear(this)
//
//        Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl)
//                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
//                .placeholder(ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY))
//                .into(this)
//    }

///
// 4.+ code
    var requestOptions : RequestOptions = RequestOptions()
        .placeholder(ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        Glide.with(context)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)  
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(this)
    }
}

fun ImageView.clear() {
    Glide.with(this.context).clear(this)
}
```

got crash at `Glide.with()`

```
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void    com.bumptech.glide.module.RegistersComponents.registerComponents(android.content.Context, com.bumptech.glide.Glide, com.bumptech.glide.Registry)"
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:270)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:223)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:184)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:168)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:689)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:716)
```

if adding the

```
@GlideModule
class DPAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun isManifestParsingEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

it will work, but since this is a library module so it should not have this one.

what might be the cause of `AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void    com.bumptech.glide.module.RegistersComponents.registerComponents(android.content.Context, com.bumptech.glide.Glide, com.bumptech.glide.Registry)"`?

anything besides GlideApp should also be avoid?

Answer (score 0):

turns out in this library module it has indirect dependency on someone who is using Glide3 and has Old GlideModule which does not impelenet the function required by the Glide 4.

Glide 4's module.registerComponents(applicationContext, glide, glide.registry); take 3 params, but Glide 3's has only two

```
 for (com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule module : manifestModules) {
      module.registerComponents(applicationContext, glide, glide.registry);
    }
```